# How to setup Android library module with productflavors and jni

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface

I'm trying to include mupdf as an android library module with precompiled .so binaries into my project.

I have an application module which includes my library module like so.

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':mupdf')
}
```

In my mupdf library module I have my compiled binaries like so.

```
mupdf
- jniLibs
  - arm64-v8a
    libmupdf.so
  - armeabi
    libmupdf.so
  - armeabi-v7a
    libmupdf.so
  - x86
    libmupdf.so
  - x86_64
    libmupdf.so
```

My build.gradle for the mupdf library project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    publishNonDefault true
    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        x64 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86_64"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
        arm_v7a {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        arm64_v8a {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "arm64-v8a"
            }
        }
        fat
    }
}
dependencies{
    compile project(':core')
}
```

The problem is soon as I add the product flavors my app doesn't compile because it doesn't find any of the java files from the mupdf module.
If I delete the product flavors part from the gradle file it compiles. But it crashes at runtime because it can't resolve/load the libmupdf library.

Comment: You should build a "fat" module for the library, with all flavors in the same **.aar** file, and apply split product flavors in `app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I have to build a fat module for the .aar library and apply the productflavors in my app.gradle.
I was missing this in my library's build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jni'
}
```

Without this no methods were able to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without product flavors. Just remove them and call `System.loadLibrary("mupdf")` on startup/at some point before the library is used. This call will figure out which native lib to use for the current devices architecture.

Comment: I wanted to use flavors to reduce the size of the apk. With every compiled binary being about 10MB, that is 50MB just compiled binaries of which only 10MB is necessary.

Comment: … but you wrote that the library cannot be loaded. Did you make some progress with this?